# GI bleeds in IV vs Oral steroids

Tags: medications

Is there any evidence of the risk of GI bleeding when comparing IV vs Oral steroids e.g. hydrocortisone Vs Prednisone Vs dexamethasone. The only information I can find is the following picture from this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6343871

There appears no comments on this in this article: http://bmjopen.bmj.com/content/4/5/e004587

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no randomized controlled trials I am aware of.  Pubmed yields nothing. Thinking physiologically, it's likely the same risk. PPI in high risk patient regardless of steroid form.

Comment: This was the only article I could find which suggested it is the same risk: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6343871

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].